# How to preserve graph properties under subgraph in MMA9

Tags: graphs-and-networks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preserving labels when using graph functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15655/preserving-labels-when-using-graph-functions)

I'm using

```
g = SocialMediaData["Twitter", "FriendNetwork"]
```

to get a nice graph with tooltips for the vertices, etc. Next, I get the weakly connected components via

```
wcc = WeaklyConnectedComponents[g]
```

and then I do

```
sg = Subgraph[g, wcc[[1]]]
```

to get the largest component. But, all the properties are gone in `sg`, i.e. I no longer have the tooltips, etc.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

```
Subgraph[g, wcc[[1]], Options[g]]
```

Comment: You can format your code by starting it with 4 spaces or selecting the text and hitting CTRL+K. See my edit in your question.